# Coin Acceptor CH-925 Pulse

Tags: arduino-uno

I got a problem where pulse voltage from acceptor is about 20mV. How can I solve my problem? and I can't detect the pulse using arduino uno. 
please any one can help ?

Comment: Output seems kind of low... Are you powering it with +12 volts?

Comment: yes I power it with +12v adapter and 1 A , it is a big problem to me since that this module doesn't exist in my country , and I wait 1 month to got it .Is their any solution?

Comment: I don't know- it just seems odd that the output voltage is 20mv. I think you've either miswired it or you have a defective unit. Check the documentation to see what output voltage you should expect.

Comment: I'm now trying to amplify this value to 5V Is this right ? or I must buy another one ?

Answer (score 1):

From [this Amazon review](https://www.amazon.co.uk/review/R3FIXHUBYXTWBI/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00C16P03I&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=560798&store=electronics):

> There are 'live' (12V), 'ground' and 'signal' wires coming out of the
>   back. Live and ground are pretty self-explanatory, and need to be
>   connected to a 12V supply - I bought a simple 1A DC one. The final
>   wire says 'signal', and needs to be connected to your circuit as input
>   into a GPIO pin in the case of a raspberry pi. It produces a pulsing
>   5V signal (Why not tell us it will be 5V somewhere in the
>   documentation? Luckily I have a multimeter) as a way of encoding which
>   type of coin it has encountered. However, raspberry pi's only want
>   3.3V signals as inputs, so you'll be wanting to make a voltage divider (With a couple of resistors - I used 33k and 18k) to safely bring that
>   5V pulse down to 3.3V. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider)
>   You'll also want to connect the ground from the device to a ground on
>   your Raspberry Pi, or the signal won't work. I did this by splicing
>   the ground cable from the power supply so that it has 2 ends - 1 for
>   the power supply to the unit, and one for the unit to the Raspberry Pi
>   Circuit.

It seems that a 5v pulse is the expected output. How are you measuring the output? You'll need a 'scope rather than a multimeter measuring voltage...

Anyway, I would not try to 'amplify' the signal, I would look to check the connections are correct and if that's not the issue, I would return the unit as defective.

Comment: I wonder if the output is actually an "open collector" type that needs a pull up resistor to 5V before you see a proper pulse. Pull-ups can be configured on the AVR input pins - which the Amazon reviewer may have done on his GPIO pin - or an external resistor could be used. Regards,

Comment: good point @Michael Vincent +1

Comment: I connected the signal to an arduino and programmed the unit  just like the videos in YouTube, the arduino cant read the signal, then I tried to detect the signal using oscilloscope, I spent 1 week on trying many solutions all of them failed, then the last thing I'm going to do is to amplify the value to 5 V, I'm wondering if their is any possible solution !

Comment: what do you mean with "scope"  You'll need a 'scope rather than a multimeter measuring voltage... ?

Comment: and the big problem is that this unit isn't available in my country and I waited about one month to get it form outside!! and bringing anther one will be time consuming .

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the signal reference the power supply ground. If your ground is floating then you won't see anything (or 20mv). If you have three wires- 12v, Gnd, and Signal, then you also need to connect the power supply ground to the arduino in order to see any signal out of the coin acceptor. Check this by connecting your meter ground to the power supply ground, and your meter + to the signal out.

Comment: Correction... Use your scope, not a meter. The coin value encoding is a pulse train (I gather) and you may not see it correctly with a meter.

Comment: I checked all connections and they are as you said, I connected the signal wire (white wire ) to analog input 0 (A0) and I read the value , it is about 7 when nothing is inserted and it's 27 when a coin is inserted ! I tried to fix the problem in code , but unfortunately all this doesn't seem to work !  what to do in this case ? Is it good option to amplify the value to 5v ?